# How do I register the property editor "TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty" in C++ Builder?

Tags: vcl, propertyeditor, c++builder-10.4-sydney, object-inspector

I have an `ImageIndex` property of the type `TImageIndex`. I need to register the property editor `TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty` to get a nice list of images to select from in the object inspector.

The only example I can find is for Delphi.

```
RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TImageIndex), TMyComponent, 'ImageIndex', TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty);
```

Translated to C++ Builder I guess it would be something like.

```
RegisterPropertyEditor(__typeinfo(TImageIndex), __classid(TMyComponent), L"ImageIndex", __classid(TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty));
```

When I compile it complains `System::Uitypes::TImageIndex (aka 'int') is not a class, namespace, or enumeration`. `__typeinfo()` is only a macro so it expands to `(PTypeInfo)TImageIndex::ClassInfo()` or more accurately `(PTypeInfo)int::ClassInfo()` since `TImageIndex` is just a typedef of `int`. Obviously `int` isn't a class with a member `ClassInfo()`, so it will not work.

So, how can register a property editor that allows me to select from a list of images?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, [`__typeinfo`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Typeinfo) only works for classes, not fundamental types.

The best way to get the necessary `PTypeInfo` pointer for a property's type, regardless of the actual type used, is to just ask the property's RTTI for the `PTypeInfo`, eg:

```
PPropInfo PropInfo = GetPropInfo(__typeinfo(TMyComponent), L"ImageIndex");
RegisterPropertyEditor(*(PropInfo->PropType), __classid(TMyComponent), L"ImageIndex", __classid(TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty));
```